# integral of $f$ over curves

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{C}, c \in [a,b]$. Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$.Use the definition to show that $$\int_{[a,b]} f dz = \int_{[a,c]} fdz + \int_{[c,b]} f dz.$$ 
So, I need to prove this by using definition of integrals of curves only.

I have done so far:
I assume $c \in [a,b]$ and $c \not \in \{a,b\}$. (Since when $c=a$ or $c=b$ it is obvious.) Then since $f$ is continuous over $[a,b]$ it is continuous over both $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$. Then, I define both $\int_{[a,c]} f dz$, and $\int_{[a,b]} f dz$ respectively. (I use parameterization and get $x(t)=(1-t)a+tc$ for the $\int_{[a,c]} f dz$ and $y(t)=(1-t)c+tb$ for $\int_{[c,b]} f dz$. (Then $0≤t≤1$)

$(-a+c)\int_0^1 f(a-t(c-a))dt + (-c+b)\int_0^1 f(c-t(b-c))dt$, but I do not know what to do as a next step to reach $\int f(a+t(b-a))(b-a)dt$.( which is $\int_{[a,b]} f dz$.)

$[a,b]$ is a notation for a curve from a to b.

can you please explain what should I do?
thanks.

Comment: Is $f$ only continuous, or you mean holomorphic?

Comment: @Gianluca: Does it matter?

Comment: @AlexM. Just to understand

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you haven't been able to prove this is because you always chose your line segments to be parametrized by $[0,1]$. It is more convenient to parametrize $[a,b]$ by $\phi : [0,1] \to [a,b]$ and let $s \in [0,1]$ be the point corresponding to $c$, i.e $c = \phi (s)$. Then

$$\int \limits _{[a,b]} f \ \Bbb d z = \int \limits _0 ^1 f(\phi(t)) \phi' (t) \ \Bbb d t = \int \limits _0 ^s f(\phi(t)) \phi' (t) \ \Bbb d t + \int \limits _s ^1 f(\phi(t)) \phi' (t) \ \Bbb d t = \int \limits _{[a,c]} f \ \Bbb d z + \int \limits _{[c,b]} f \ \Bbb d z .$$